# How to define types in a DSL in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, abstract-syntax-tree, dsl, gadt

I've been writing an AST to build a DSL in Haskell and, for that, I'm using GADTs to define expressions such as:

```
data Expr a where
    I   :: Int  -> Expr Int
    B   :: Bool -> Expr Bool
    Add :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
    Mul :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
    Eq  :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Bool
```

However, I would like for expressions like Add and Mul to also work with other numeric values, from types Float and Double.
How would I be able to achieve such results?

Comment: For your simple use case it can be simply - `Add :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a`

Comment: @AnupamJain That should probably be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generalize `Expr` a bit and use

```
data Expr a where
  Lit :: a -> Expr a                           -- why not just let anything in?
  Add :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a   -- only `a` w/ `Num a` can be added
  Mul :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a   -- only `a` w/ `Num a` can be multiplied
  Eq  :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool -- only `a` w/ `Eq a` can be added
```

Then again, the question really is: *what are you trying to do with it*? If you just want to explicitly construct an AST that type-checks and then be able to evaluate it, the above works just fine.

```
eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (Lit x) = x
eval (Add x y) = eval x + eval y
eval (Mul x y) = eval x * eval y
eval (Eq x y) = eval x == eval y
```